# Wordpress Routing not working in Digital Ocean using nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, mod-rewrite, droplet

I am struggling with this from quite sometime now and thought to ask the community.

I have recently started working on digital ocean and nginx. I was using apache earlier.

I have a simple wordpress website that works fine in local but when pushed on droplet server using nginx the site is not working properly.

The landing page is working fine but when i route to different link I get 404 error page from nginx.

I feel this is because of htaccess file that is not getting picked up in nginx and I have to rewrite rules in nginx but nothing worked.

Here is my configuration file for nginx.conf file, sites-available/default file

**sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name martinschildrenacademy.com www.martinschildrenacademy.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
         }
    }

    # Default server configuration
    #
    server {
    #       listen 80 default_server;
    #       listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name martinschildrenacademy.com www.martinschildrenacademy.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/martinschildrenacademy.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/martinschildrenacademy.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name martinschildrenacademy.com;

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;#
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
  }
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml     application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Any suggestion that could help me to solve this issue?

Comment: did you try manually install wordpress or follow some tutorial, it is a permalink issue. try [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: No wordpress is perfectly fine. I just got the issue fixed. Not sure why the top server block was not considered. Just added the answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have two server blocks in your **sites-available/default** file. The first server block receives HTTP requests and then responds with redirect instructions to the HTTPS version defined with the second server block. You only need to keep the first 3 lines inside the first block and remove the rest like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name martinschildrenacademy.com www.martinschildrenacademy.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Nginx configuration for WordPress must have the following location block to work correctly:

```
location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

So you must insert the location block into the second server block. You did. And it worked.

Comment: Hi @Tom Thank you. Noted and changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this working.

Not sure why but I just moved this line

```
location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

in default.config file from top to bottom server block. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```